# Singleton-Like UIView Access?

Tags: ios, objective-c, singleton

I have a UIView I need to access the properties of from all around my app. I know you can't create a Singleton around a UIView object, so what might be a good way of doing similar?

E.g. The view has a label. From any view controller in my app I want to be able to change the text of this view (sitting in a parent view controller).

Thanks.

EDIT:

Success! Using KVO to track changes in my Singleton object worked a charm, and a very simple solution.

Answer (score 11, accepted):

I think what you’re trying to do violates the separation of concerns of the MVC pattern: The only thing that should interact with a view is its controller. In your case, you should probably be creating a model that is watched by your view controller (maybe through [key–value observing](https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/general/conceptual/DevPedia-CocoaCore/KVO.html)), and then the controller can propagate the necessary changes to your view.

Comment: Key-value observing, not KVC, would be the technology you'd want to use, but otherwise, this was going to be my exact proposal.

Comment: @CarlVeazey Whoops, you’re right. I’ve edited my answer. Thanks!

Comment: +1, but please remove "singleton". Why should the model be a singleton? I realize that the OP said "from all around my app", but there are better ways to accomplish that.

Comment: You can also post custom "change" notifications and have your view controller listen to them.

Comment: I don't personally see why a Singleton wouldn't be a terrible idea? If you could suggest an alternative if you think there is a better one, great. But for now, I have attempted using KVO in my singleton. Check my original post, I have added some extra details. Hope you cam help, thanks.

Answer (score 0):

If you know (read: you really know for now and forever!) that there will be at most one instance of that view alive at one point in time, you can just use a global variable to store that. Or use a class property on that view - which is as close as being a singleton as possible.

Or you might just fix your design, which has proven to be the better choice in every case I can remember. :) Just add some forward and backward references in your classes (and stick to MVC principle). It takes much less time to implement that worrying about those awkward workaround, and it will pay of rather sooner than later.